# Not getting the correct degrees of freedom in R

Tags: r, statistics, anova

I'm unsure what I'm doing wrong. This is the data that I'm using:

```
dtf <- read.table(text=
"Litter Treatment Tube.L
      1   Control   1641
      2   Control   1290
      3   Control   2411
      4   Control   2527
      5   Control   1930
      6   Control   2158
      1        GH   1829
      2        GH   1811
      3        GH   1897
      4        GH   1506
      5        GH   2060
      6        GH   1207
      1       FSH   3395
      2       FSH   3113
      3       FSH   2219
      4       FSH   2667
      5       FSH   2210
      6       FSH   2625
      1    GH+FSH   1537
      2    GH+FSH   1991
      3    GH+FSH   3639
      4    GH+FSH   2246
      5    GH+FSH   1840
      6    GH+FSH   2217", header=TRUE)
```

What I did was:

```
BoarsMod1 <- aov(Tube.L ~ Litter + Treatment, data=dtf)
anova(BoarsMod1)
```

I'm getting an incorrect number of degrees of freedom for `litter`. It should be 5 (as there are 6 litter blocks) but it is 1. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Because your column `Litter` is numeric. Change it to `factor`.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent how would I do that?

Comment: `df$Litter <- factor(df$Litter)`.

Comment: @RuiBarradas I got the following error: Error in df$Litter : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable

Comment: `dtf`, not `df`, the name of your dataframe

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent thank you that worked!

Comment: Sorry, I missed the argument `data` of the `aov` instruction where you have posted the name of your data.frame. @StéphaneLaurent is right, it's `dtf`.